# Questions about Spark Datasource API v2

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to understand more about Spark datasource API v2. Spark datasource API v2 provides org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Table interface, and my understanding is that this Table interface and its implementation are "v2CatalogTable" and CatalogTable is an old concept in datasource API v1. Spark does provide backward compatibility by providing V1Table that extends org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Table and takes CatalogTable as parameter. Is it a correct understanding? If so, what is the corresponding interface for CatalogTablePartition?

I'm trying to see if my understanding for data source api v2 is correct or not.